# Call application using quartz job

Tags: c#, console-application, quartz.net

I want to write quartz job which will call my installed application.

For example I have console app :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Datetime.Now());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and I publish this app on my windows machine. Now I write this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        var sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>()
            .WithIdentity("testjob", "testgroup")
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("testtrigger", "testgroup")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

}


public class TestJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Here I want to call my app
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: use Process.Start and add the parameters for your first console EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Execute()` method, call the application executable you need to invoke:

```
// eg: "C:/MyApp/app.exe"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PathToApplication.exe");
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)